# SQL Server Transaction Log Explorer/Analyzer

Tags: sql-server

What options are available for rolling back transactions after the fact in SQL Server?

I'm looking to have a plan in place *before* somebody deletes 10,000 of the wrong rows.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008 I think it is just Apex.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I did not know that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [RedGate SQL Log rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm) (Sorry, SQL Server 2000 only. News to me)
- [Apex SQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

I'm sure there used to be more. Back when I was a prod DBA I couldn't get through a week without some irritating Sales muppet trying to flog me a GUI or tool.

I would also suggest you take regular backups with FULL recovery. A 10k rows *update* may have subsequent changes that will invalidate any rollback.

FWIW, I've never seen the need for one. No-one can delete 10k rows in my DB anyway unless it's designed that way: why would I allow someone to run DELETE directly?

Comment: Thanks for sharing Transaction Log Explorer tools for SQL. At last I accidentally deleted few records from my database table then I tried SysTools SQL Log Analyzer and i recovered those records successfully. I am not comparing it from other log Explorer tools, but in my scenario this one is really helpful for me. 

NOTE: Try at your behalf http://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-log-analyzer.html

Comment: Apex is $2000, Toad can generate undo scripts is $655, SysTools SQL Log Analyzer is $300