# Retrieve database information from DBML files

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, crash, data-migration

I'm working on one project using ASP.Net 4.0 and SQL Server 2012. I have used DBML files for data access layer and Unfortunately, the database is got corrupted due to hard disk crash and not able to get the database.

Is it possible to retrieve the following things from DBML?

- Tables (I didn't drag the tables into DBML before)
- Stored procedures with body
- Triggers

Help would be highly appreciated .

Thanks,
Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. If you have database backups you can restore these and get the details from there.

If you don’t have these but your database was in full recovery mode you can try to examine transaction log and see if you can get any info from there.

See this for more details

[SQL Server Transaction Log Explorer/Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789443/sql-server-transaction-log-explorer-analyzer)