# SQL Server - user permissions/securables change report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a default report in Sql Server that will output the permissions/securables history for given user or login?  If not, does anyone know how to craft such a query?  We had an incident recently where a user mysteriously lost insert permissions on a table, and we'd like to find out exactly what caused it.

Comment: I don't think the history is retained in any table. You'd have to use a log inspector, like Apex or Red Gate provide.  The system table you want to examine the log of would be `sys.database_permissions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to figure this out is to read transaction log that stores details on each transaction. If your database was in full recovery mode then the info is somewhere in there.

Unfortunately you can’t do this using standard tools because MS doesn’t support this.

You can either get yourself a commercial log reader or try to hack this using undocumented commands like fn_dblog.

Check these out for more details

[Read the log file (*.LDF) in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054/read-the-log-file-ldf-in-sql-server-2008)

[SQL Server Transaction Log Explorer/Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789443/sql-server-transaction-log-explorer-analyzer)

[How to view transaction logs in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query for finding the permissions on a database. We have been using a variant of this query to copy permissions from one table to another table.

```
select *
   FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
   INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
   INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking more for an audit query - I want to know what process/person exactly changed this users permissions.

Comment: If that information is stored in SQL, I have not seen it/do not know where to find it. The next thing that's pops into my mind is writing a trigger. But I don't know how well that would work with schema info.